# is it ok to refer field of the class in initialization list?

Tags: c++

I wrote such class:

```
class FastDecoder
{
public:
    FastDecoder(void);
    ~FastDecoder(void);
private:
    SnapshotMessageBuilder messageBuilder;
    DecodedMsg const& decodedMsg;
};
```

If it is correct to use `messageBuilder` to initialize `decodedMsg`?

```
FastDecoder::FastDecoder(void):
    decodedMsg(messageBuilder.GetDecodedMsg())
{
```

I suspect that as FastDecoder is not yet constructed then not all fields are probaly initialized and so I can have runtime error triing to access `messageBuilder`

If my code is not good then how to rewrite it better? Will it keep working if I reorder fields like that:

```
private:
    DecodedMsg const& decodedMsg;
    SnapshotMessageBuilder messageBuilder;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will it keep working if I reorder fields like that [...]?

**No**, because data members are initialized in the order in which they are *declared* in the class definition. As a result, the initialization of `decodedMsg` would occur first, and that means you would be calling `GetDecodedMsg()` on an object which has not been constructed yet.

Your current version, on the other hand, is OK, because `messageBuilder` will have already been constructed by the time you are initializing `decodedMsg`.

Comment: i really don't like things like that - when i reorder fields declarations and everything crached. should I refactor my class somehow to avoid "fields declarations order dependency"?

Comment: @javapowered: Sounds like a good idea. Why do you need the `decodedMsg` reference btw? Can't you just call `messageBuilder.GetDecodedMsg()` when needed?

Comment: i need it only for performance and readability a little bit. i'm writing low latency code.

Comment: @javapowered: Sounds like premature optimization to me. The compiler may well optimize things behind the hood - try it the clean way first, measure performance, and only if you can prove you have a bottleneck, think of optimization. I'd personally not use a reference here.

Comment: it's obviosly that may version is not slower. it would be insane to measure performance of every single method call.

Comment: @javapowered: Well, it's not always obvious. The compiler may inline the call for instance, so that your version won't be slower, but not even faster than the version with the explicit call. Or it may be faster, but way less than you think, which would not justify making the design fragile. When performance is concerned, the motto is "measure, measure, measure". Design for clarity and simplicity, and optimize only when you can prove that it is necessary.